# Quicksort going in infinite loop

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to write the code for quicksort but it keeps on going in infinte loop , I have tried hard to find the error in following code ,can anybody help please.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int arr[100];

void quicksort(int low,int high)
{
    int i = low,j = high,pivotIndex,pivot;
    pivotIndex = rand()%20;
    pivot = arr[pivotIndex];

    if(i>=j)
        return;

    while(i<j)
    {

        while(arr[i]<pivot && i<j)
        {
            i++;
        }

        while(arr[j]>pivot && j>i)
        {
            j--;
        }

        if(i<j)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }

    }
    quicksort(low,i);
    quicksort(i+1,high);
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        arr[i] = rand()%21;

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    quicksort(0,19);

    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
            printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DEVENDERGOYAL: Your edit changed the question, and actually fixed one of the bugs in it, one of the issues in this question is this bug. Make sure that when you edit - you do not change the question itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pivot selection is wrong, you should chose a pivot in (index) range `[low,high)`, while you chose a pivot in range `[0,20)`:

```
pivotIndex = rand()%20;
```

It will later make the partition not go well, and the value of `i`, which you later use to recurse - will be wrong.

---

**EDIT:**

One more issue is with the partitioning, it should also consider what to do with the pivot element and its duplicates - there should be some kind of "tie breaker" - the pivot should go to one side of the array (or some alternative).

For example, assume the pivot is `5` and the array is `[5,3,8,5]`:

You will just infinitely swap the 5's over and over, which is definetly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the author of a sorting plugin I can assure you that reinventing these kind of algorithms can really bite you in the proverbial . ;o)

Particular attention (as mentioned already) has to be given to choosing the pivot, how arithmetic is going to influence the pivot value (for instance, VBA does its integer arithmetic in floating point, causing all sorts of weirdness), where the 'leftovers' go, how the final step handles the last partition (you would not be the first to skip a few records here).

Here's a link for sorting algorithms in many languages:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort

Answer (score -1):

```
 pivotIndex = rand()%20;
 pivot = arr[pivotIndex];
```

Here each time you call the quick sort your pivotIndex might not in range(low,high).
You can use

```
pivotIndex = low+rand()%(high-low);
```

I am sure this will generate the pivotIndex with in range.

Comment: `I am sure this will generate the pivotIndex with in range.` It will not, consider low=10,high=20, and the initial array has only 20 elements. (The result could be pivotIndex==29) You should also let him figure this one out after pointing the problem, IMO.